# Send App back to Recent app stack android

Tags: android, android-activity

I am working on a WebRtc Calling App. When my application is in background when incoming call come the Calling Activity PopsUp for call . And When call hung Up i need to send app to the recent background state.
So i came around a solution `moveTaskToBack()`, which is working perfectly but the problem is after calling Activity finish it shows the Last Activity for 2 or 3 seconds and then going back to recent app. Also tried in `onStop()` but the result remain the same .

```
  @Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    moveTaskToBack(true);
}
```

Is there a better Alternative of  `moveTaskToBack()` without any Delay? If anyone need more clarification on question let me know in comments. Thanks in advance.

Comment: use a [popBackStack](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html#popBackStack()) instead.

Comment: Dunno. I'm not very familiar with `moveTaskToBack()`. Does `finish()` by itself not do what you want? That is, I'm not quite sure what you're trying to do, here.

Comment: finish() poping up the last activity in stack to foreground. MovetaskBack is working as needed but with a certain delay (3 seconds approx).Anyway Thx for your attention .

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't do it [onDestroy](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onDestroy()), because it's not guaranteed that to be called in [Activity Lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle.html).

> In the onStop() method, the app should release almost all resources that aren't needed while the user is not using it. For example, if you registered a BroadcastReceiver in onStart() to listen for changes that might affect your UI, you can unregister the broadcast receiver in onStop(), as the user can no longer see the UI. It is also important that you use onStop() to release resources that might leak memory, because it is possible for the system to kill the process hosting your activity without calling the activity's final onDestroy() callback.

Problem might be the time takes to calling onDestroy. You can try to call it where you are finishing activity.

Comment: Same Result in onStop() with moveTaskToBack.